# How to get the elements by indices in the tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

```
data = tf.constant( [ [ [0, 2, 4, 1], [1, 0, 0, 2] ], [ [1, 0, 4, 6], [2, 6, 3, 1] ] ] ) 
indices = tf.argmax(data, axis=2)
```

How to get the result `[ [4 2], [6 6] ]` in tensorflow?
Please help me!!!!

Comment: can you include your tensorflow code for `data` and `indices`?

Comment: data = tf.constant( [[ [ [0 2 4 1], [1 0 0 2] ], [ [1 0 4 6], [2 6 3 1] ] ] )
indices = tf.argmax(data, axis=2)

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.reduce_max()`, in your case

```
data = tf.constant([[ [0, 2, 4, 1],[1, 0, 0, 2]], [ [1, 0, 4, 6], [2, 6, 3, 1] ]])
maximum_values = tf.reduce_max(data, reduction_indices=[2])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    p=sess.run(maximum_values)
    print(p)

[[4 2]
[6 6]]
```

Edit: To access other values you could slice by indexes and then use `tf.concat` or `tf.stack`. For example, if you want to get `[[0 2] [3 1]]` you could try

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    p=sess.run(data[0][0][0:2])
    print(p)
    [0 2]

    q=sess.run(data[1][1][2:])
    print(q)
    [3 1]

    r=sess.run(tf.stack([p,q],0))
    print(r)
    [[0 2]
    [3 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  If the indices are not the subscript of the maximum value, but the specific value, how do I get it?  Such as indices is [ [ 0, 2], [ 3, 1] ]. I tried using gather but it didn't work.

Comment: Check the edit in my answer. Probably the only way is by slicing indexes, and then you might need `tf.concat`, `tf.stack` or `tf.reshape` for specific format.